# ¿Hacer un UNION y hacer una tercera consulta MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Mi problema es que estoy haciendo un `UNION` para mostrar la información de dos tablas y a la vez unir los resultados, hasta ahí todo bien, pero después necesito hacer una tercera consulta para mostrar la imagen que corresponda a la unión de cada elemento de las 2 primeras consultas, es ahí donde no tengo idea de como proseguir, más o menos se vería así:

[imagen de perfil] - Juan

[imagen de perfil] - Carlos

[imagen de perfil] - Andrés

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
SELECT destino FROM inboxs
WHERE destino='$username' OR de='$username'
UNION
SELECT de FROM inboxs
WHERE destino='$username' OR de='$username'
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no parece tener mucho sentido asi como esta, es mas parece que tratas de resolver un problema de como mostrar datos, haciendo un query raro en la base de datos. Tal vez sea mejor que digas que intentas solucionar con esto...

Comment: Ok, gracias @gbianchi, tal vez deba replantear la pregunta, gracias.